# Using lazy loading AND webp images with JPG fallback

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, webp

I am currently lazy loading 'jpg' images using the [unveil.js](https://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) script and it works fine.

I simply serve a placeholder image and eventually the image path is populated by the path in a data attribute. Here is my HTML...

```
<img class="unveil" src="blank.png" alt="Variation 2" data-src="variant2.jpg">
```

and I call the function...

```
$(".unveil").unveil();
```

Now the problem is, I would like to add WebP images to my website but with a jpg fallback as WebP isn't supported in previous versions of Safari.

Ideally I would use this markup...

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="variant2.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img class="unveil" src="blank.png" alt="Variation 2" data-src="variant2.jpg">
</picture>
```

**Questions**

1. How would I modify the code to swap both the jpg source AND the WebP source? Is it possible to do this AND still use lazy loading?
2. Would be easier to detect webp support upfront?
3. Should I just not use lazy loading on webp images as they are small enough and continue using the script as is for jpgs incase webp isn't supported?

For reference, here is the code for the unveil.js script...

```
;(function($) {

  $.fn.unveil = function(threshold, callback) {

    var $w = $(window),
        th = threshold || 0,
        retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1,
        attrib = retina? "data-src-retina" : "data-src",
        images = this,
        loaded;

    this.one("unveil", function() {
      var source = this.getAttribute(attrib);
      source = source || this.getAttribute("data-src");
      if (source) {
        this.setAttribute("src", source);
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback.call(this);
      }
    });

    function unveil() {
      var inview = images.filter(function() {
        var $e = $(this);
        if ($e.is(":hidden")) return;

        var wt = $w.scrollTop(),
            wb = wt + $w.height(),
            et = $e.offset().top,
            eb = et + $e.height();

        return eb >= wt - th && et <= wb + th;
      });

      loaded = inview.trigger("unveil");
      images = images.not(loaded);
    }

    $w.on("scroll.unveil resize.unveil lookup.unveil", unveil);

    unveil();

    return this;

  };

})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
```

Comment: Why not just use the new `loading="lazy"` attribute?

Comment: This would be ideal but doesn't seem to be supported on Safari or iOS

Comment: That is true. You have to put in balance the pros and cons in your specific case. For example how much "SEO-harm" does it do to use these "blank" images versus not having lazy loading for some users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your first question, but here's what you could do:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp"
    srcset=".."
    sizes="..">
  <source type="image/jpeg"
    srcset=".."
    sizes="..">
  <img src="default.jpg"
    loading="lazy"
    alt="..">
</picture>
```

to 2) i would do it this way, so no
to 3) lazy is always a good way if you have images that a not that important and not above the fold.
Also think about to set width and height attribute on  that the browser can reserve the correct space.

Comment: Thanks. I agree using the loading lazy attribute would be ideal however it's not supported on Safari or iOS meaning most mobile users won't get the benefit.

Comment: ok i see, thats correct. i see no options for this on the page of unveil.js. maybe another script could be a solution? Then i would recommend https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill - thats have support for picture tag and differecnt sources.